# Java program is not printing to the end

Tags: java, csv, txt, export-to-text

Hi I have an issue with my simple app. It is printing from csv file some text to the txt file it is working well, but not to the end, It stops at like 90% and ends. It doesn't matter how many rows are in the csv file it stops like in half of model and ends

I was increasing and decrasing number of rows, tried to print models in console and it worked, i am using Filewrtitter

Comment: so many possibilities.... maybe you should include a [mre] in the question - otherwise expect only more or less wild guesses (e.g. forgetting to close or/and flush the file)

Comment: We need to see the code, otherwise we could just guess what the problem is…

Comment: Just a guess: If the program suddenly stops running before it is supposed to, there should be some sort of error message. There is mistake I often see in code posted on Stack Overflow: The programmer has code to `catch` an exception, but the interior of the catch block has no code. In other words, the exception is ignored. If you have catch blocks that ignore the exception, try changing them to do something with the exception. Doing this might be a good lesson in debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason is that you are not closing your FileWriter after use.
Instead of this structure:

```
    var fileWriter = new FileWriter("filename.txt");
    // use fileWriter here
```

Try doing it like this:

```
    try (var fileWriter = new FileWriter("filename.txt")) {
        // use fileWriter here
    }
```

The try-with-resources statement will then automatically close your writer.

Comment: Even though the O/P accepted this answer, in my opinion, this answer falls short. It does not this explain why the O/P's code processes 90% of the input, and stops abruptly. As they currently stand, both the question and this answer deserve down votes.